# Permission denied when moving directory in VLC

Tags: windows-7, permissions, vlc-media-player, build

I am trying to build VLC in Windows with [Mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) and [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys). When I run the following commands:

```
../bootstrap --build=i686-w64-mingw32
make prebuilt
```

This error stops the build process:

```
mv: cannot move `i686-w64-mingw32' to `../i686-w64-mingw32': Permission denied
make: *** [prebuilt] Error 1
```

What is this error, and how do I solve it? Even though I have write access to the directory, and I've edited the files as per the Mingw website, I am still stuck with this error.

Solved the problem by setting: export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/win32/lib/pkgconfig at the beginning of the compilation instructions. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Do you have permissions to write on the parent folder as well?

Comment: Yes, and I run the msys.bat command as an administrator... and still nothing